# How to add custom data instances to an array in Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a question where and how to properly save users who are logged into a rooms, now I save them inside the collection "rooms" but I save the user as a reference

[image: How it looks in firebase]

```
func addUserToRoom(room: String, id: String) {
    COLLETCTION_ROOMS.document(room).updateData(["members": FieldValue.arrayUnion([COLLETCTION_USERS.document(id)])])
}
```

But when I create a rooms, I need to pass in an array of users

```
func fetchRooms() {
    Firestore.firestore()
        .collection("rooms")
        .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ in
            guard let rooms = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            
            self.rooms = rooms.map({ (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> VoiceRoom in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                let query = queryDocumentSnapshot.get("members") as? [DocumentReference]
                
// ========  I'm making a request here, but I don't understand how to save users next

                query.map { result in
                    result.map { user in
                        let user = user.getDocument { userSnapshot, _ in
                            let data = userSnapshot?.data()
                            guard let user = data else { return }

                            let id = user["id"] as? String ?? ""
                            let first_name = user["first_name"] as? String ?? ""
                            let last_name = user["last_name"] as? String ?? ""

                            let profile = Profile(id: id,
                                                  first_name: first_name,
                                                  last_name: last_name)
                        }
                    }
                }

                let id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
                let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
                let description = data["description"] as? String ?? ""
                let members = [Profile(id: "1", first_name: "Test1", last_name: "Test1")]
                
                return VoiceRoom(id: id,
                                 title: title,
                                 description: description,
                                 members: members
                })
        }
}
```

This is how my room and profile model looks like

```
struct VoiceRoom: Identifiable, Decodable {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var members: [Profile]?
}

struct Profile: Identifiable, Decodable {
    var id: String 
    var first_name: String?
    var last_name: String?
}
```

Maybe someone can tell me if I am not saving users correctly and I need to do it in a separate collection, so far I have not found a solution, I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: "users who are logged into a rooms"  You are the only person who understand the relationship between those entities.  And you are not explaining it.

Comment: You can store UIDs of users in an array in the document of that room.

Comment: @ElTomato I added a picture of how it looks like in my database

Comment: Unfortunately the image isn't very helpful and the terminology 'create rooms' and 'save users' is a bit ambiguous without more context. I think my question is; if you have a room document, and one of the fields is an array that stores userId's, what's the problem with loading that data in your code into a class or some other object that holds the data? In that case you're just loading the uid's into an object with an array. No? Can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like this answer is going to blow your mind:

```
struct VoiceRoom: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var members: [Profile]?
}

struct Profile: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String
    var first_name: String?
    var last_name: String?
}

final class RoomRepository: ObservableObject {
    @Published var rooms: [VoiceRoom] = []
    private let db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var listener: ListenerRegistration?
    
    func addUserToRoom(room: VoiceRoom, user: Profile) {
        let docRef = COLLECTION_ROOMS.document(room.id)
        let userData = try! Firestore.Encoder().encode(user)
        docRef.updateData(["members" : FieldValue.arrayUnion([userData])])
    }
    func fetchRooms() {
        listener = db.collection("rooms").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ in
            guard let roomDocuments = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            self.rooms = roomDocuments.compactMap { try? $0.data(as: VoiceRoom.self) }
        }
    }
}
```

And that's it. This is all it takes to correctly store members of a room and simply decode a stored room into an instance of `VoiceRoom`. All of it is pretty self explanatory but if you have any questions feel free to ask it in the comments.

P.S. I changed `COLLETCTION_ROOMS` to `COLLECTION_ROOMS`

## Edit:

I decided to elaborate on my changes anyway so that people who just started coding can understand how I reduced the code to just a few lines (skip this if you understood my code).

When your custom data instances conform to the `Codable` protocol it allows those instances to be automatically transformed into data the database can store (known as Encoding) AND allows them to converted back into the concrete types in your code when you retrieve them from the database (known as Decoding). And the magic of it is all you need to do is add `: Codable` to your structs and classes to get all this functionality for free!

Now, what about the functions? The `addUserToRoom(room:user:)` function takes in a `VoiceRoom` instead of a `String` because it's generally easier for the caller to just pass in `room` instead of `room.id`. This extra step can be done by the function itself and saves a little bit of clutter in your Views while also making it easier.

Finally the `fetchRooms()` function attaches a listener to the "rooms" collection and fires a block of code any time the collection changes in any way. In the block of code, I check if the document snapshot actually contains documents by using `guard let roomDocuments = snapshot?.documents else { return }`. After I know I have the documents all that's left to do is convert those documents back into `VoiceRoom` instances which can easily be done because `VoiceRoom` conforms to `Codable` (Remember how I said: "AND allows them to converted back into the concrete types in your code when you retrieve them from the database"). I do this by mapping the array of `[QueryDocumentSnapshot]` i.e. `roomDocuments`, into concrete `VoiceRoom` instances. I use a compact map because if any of the documents fail to decode it won't be contained in `self.rooms`.

So 
`try? $0.data(as: VoiceRoom.self)` 
**tries** to take every **document** (represented by `$0`) and represent its **"data"** **"as"** **"VoiceRoom"** instances.

And that's all it takes!

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer, I understand that in your example everything is done automatically, but I want to know this way too
**let members = data["members"] as? [Profile] ?? []**
So can it be done ?

Comment: Yes it can. Just move `self.rooms = ... ` to the innermost completion handler. Once you have all the data you need you can assign the final `VoiceRoom` array to `self.rooms`. However I heavily advise against it because my method saves you on reads which in turn saves you money (if you're planning to make this app a commercial thing and not just as a hobby). It also makes for a better user experience as it's faster and it's just 1 network call instead of thousands of little ones.